# SQL Azure table relations

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure

I have a simple database schema.

Table **TAGS** and table **USERS**.

How I can make a column in USERS table with List of TAGS ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds that it is most likely to have `Many-to-Many` relationship.

Users Table

- UserID  (**PK**)
- UserName
- OtherFields...

Tags Table

- TagID  (**PK**)
- TagName
- OtherFields...

UserTagLink Table

- UserID  (**FK**)
- TagID (**FK**)

you need to join both tables

```
SELECT  a.*, c.*    -- <<== select the columns you want to display
FROM    Users a
        INNER JOIN UserTagLink b
            ON a.UserID = b.UserID
        INNER JOIN Tags c
            ON b.TagID = c.TagID
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Comment: Yes but I ask aboud desing this in schema. How to make schema?

Comment: Great! But this is one way to do it?

Comment: It's the best way to do it.